# Problems With Birt On Eclipse 2019-12 (O/S Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am having problems getting BIRT to display report design on eclipse 2019-12.

I have spent hours trying to resolve this. I have tried installing BIRT from the Indigo, Kepler, Mars ... Repositories as so many posts have suggested but I always end up with the following error when trying to open a report design (I obviously can create the report):

Plug-in "org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.editors.ReportEditorProxy".

Any useful advice would be much appreciated.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.editors.ReportEditorProxy".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:212)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:929)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.lambda$0(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:284)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:231)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:321)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:338)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:967)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:331)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1297)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:547)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:531)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:51)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:64)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:680)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:665)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:676)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:660)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/birt/report/designer/ui/editors/IDEMultiPageReportEditor
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:204)
... 133 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.lib (161).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:425)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:929)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.views.ElementAdapterManager.(ElementAdapterManager.java:97)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.preferences.PreferenceFactory.getPreferences(PreferenceFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.preferences.PreferenceFactory.getPreferences(PreferenceFactory.java:44)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ReportPlugin.start(ReportPlugin.java:281)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:425)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
... 133 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:612)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
... 171 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPluginDescriptor
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:825)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:778)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
... 174 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPluginDescriptor cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.lib_4.7.0.v201706222054
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:514)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:425)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 183 more
```

Regards
Steve

Comment: What's the related stack trace? Have you tried the current release, 2020-12?

Comment: Yes I have tried 2020-12 but BIRT does not seem to be included in the repository.

Comment: I have added the stack trace to my post, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Eclipse are not compatible with the BIRT designer plugin anymore as you can see from the *NoClassDefFoundError* (newer Eclipse versions are using libraries that conflict with the ones used by the BIRT plugin). Unfortunately, it seems that BIRT is not maintained anymore (at least the open source version).

My solution was to download the "All-in-one" package from the [BIRT downloads page](https://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/), this is an Eclipse Neon editor already bundled with the designer plugin. I use the latest Eclipse for editing code and the older one for editing reports.